# How to insert/view primary key (email) from auto-generated views with grails (create/list.gsp)?

Tags: grails, view, mapping, primary-key, gsp

I have legacy Database Schema (PostgreSQL) I cant change it. I'm having problems mapping my class with a database model, this is what I want and what I have:

-> Database Schema - **DataTable Users** - *PostgreSQL*

> PK id STRING (email), password STRING

-> My model - **Domain Users**

> PK email STRING, password STRING

I need be able to let to the users insert via the **create.gsp** *view* the id (email) of the user, i dont want to change manually the **create.gsp** or other **.gsp** I want ***Grails*** auto-generate the views for me.

So, ***How can i do to auto-generate the views showing the primary key like other field to let final user insert/see it?***

In my *Domain* I have something like this:

```
class Usuario {
    String id
    String password

    static constraints = {
        id email: true
        password blank:false, nullable:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'usuario'
        version false
        id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
    }

    String toString(){
        return id
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my english!

**UPDATE:**

I just try to insert [the following piece of code] into my **user controller** and now i can see the **id** field, but only when I create a new user **create.gsp**, when I show list of users in the **list.gsp** I cant see the field **id** (email)

```
def scaffold = Usuario
```

**UPDATE II:**

I have followed the comment from [user1128791](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128791/user1128791) and it worked for me, I install the **templates system** and then I worked over it, changing *list.gsp* form *src/templates/scaffolding* to show the id field, something like this:

```
excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version' << 'id'
allowedNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
```

for this

```
excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version'
allowedNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated' << 'id'
```

**UPDATE III:**

I've gone further and made ​​the following changes, to work only with my *email* field and *password* field.

```
class User {
    String email
    String password

    static transients = ['id']

    void setId(String email) {
       id = email
    }

    String getId() {
       return email
   }

   static constraints = {
       email email: true, blank:false, nullable:false
       password blank:false, nullable:false
   }
    static mapping = {
        table 'usuario'
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'email'
        email column: 'id'
    }

    String toString(){
        return id
    }
}
```

To enable you to have the maximum amount of information about my problem and how i solved it, thats what i'm mapping:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario
(
   id text NOT NULL,
   "password" text,
    CONSTRAINT "PK usuario" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.grails.org/Artifact+and+Scaffolding+Templates:

To customize the templates for you project you need to the install the templates:

```
grails install-templates
```

This will create the src/templates folder in your project which will contain various artifact and scaffolding templates.

Than you will have to change each *.gsp template to render a textfield instead of hidden field for ID's.

EDIT: Looking into the templates. Grails 2.0 should do this automaticaly for 'assigned' id's.

Comment: I add **def scaffold = Usuario** into my **user controlle** and now i can see the **id** field, but only when i create a new user **create.gsp**, when I show list of users in the **list.gsp** I cant see the field **id** (email). I'll try to edit a template, and i'll let you know. Thanks